# Trying to wrap my mind around awful SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

Can someone please help me understand what exactly this query does?

```
SELECT pp.Sedol
    ,MAX(MAX(Id)) OVER (
        PARTITION BY pp.Sedol
        ,MAX(pp.ValueDate)
        ) PriceId
FROM Prices pp
GROUP BY pp.Sedol
```

Comment: You can't aggregate within an aggregate function. This should throw a syntax error.

Comment: Well, unfortunately it doesn't. I didn't write this, I'm just trying to understand what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: @JaazCole: *"You can't aggregate within an aggregate function."* [Apparently, you can](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c971/1), at least if you're using a window function.

Comment: I think that this will just do the same that `SELECT Sedol, MAX(Id) PriceId FROM Prices GROUP BY Sedol`. The Second `MAX` seems to come from a misunderstanding of how to do this thing. And @JaazCole, this actually won't throw a syntax error

Comment: @Lamak So the MAX(pp.ValueDate) clause inside the PARTITION BY doesn't actually do anything?

Comment: @FrantišekŠkandera It does something, just not something useful (in the sense that it would change the results). So, the `MAX(MAX(Id)) OVER(PARTITION BY Sedol, MAX(ValueDate))` will get the maximum value of `Id` for every combination of `Sedol, MAX(ValueDate)`, and to that result set, is obtaining the `MAX` value of `Id`, grouped by `Sedol` (at least, that's how it looks to me). So, it ultimately should be the same results that you would obtain performing a single `MAX(Id)`

Comment: @Lamak Thank you, I'm starting to understand. You've been a big help. :)

Comment: @FrantišekŠkandera: Now that you know what the query does, could you please reveal the secret of what a "sedol" is? I find that word strangely intriguing. :)

Comment: @stakx http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEDOL :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is equivalent to:

```
with x as (
  select
    Sedol,
    max(id) max_id,
    Max(ValueDate) max_valuedate
  from
    Prices
  group by
    Sedol
) select
  Sedol,
  max(max_id) over (partition by Sedol, max_valuedate) PriceId
from
  x;
```

Although as Lamak says, I can't see any way this isn't going to just be equivalent to

```
SELECT Sedol, MAX(Id) PriceId FROM Prices GROUP BY Sedol
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0c1fe/2)

Answer (score 1):

I think Lamak has already explained about the sql, I am posting an example for understanding.
You can see both the sqls give same results. Copy paste below code in sql server and try:

```
declare @Prices table (Id int, ValueDate datetime, Sedol int)

Insert into @Prices values (1,'2014-09-06' ,200),
(2,'2014-09-07' , 100),
(3,'2014-09-08' , 100),
(4,'2014-09-09' , 100),
(5,'2014-09-10' , 300),
(6,'2014-09-11' , 300),
(7,'2014-09-12' , 100),
(8,'2014-09-13' , 200),
(9,'2014-09-14' , 200),
(10,'2014-09-15' , 200)

Select * from @Prices

-- Your SQL
SELECT pp.Sedol
    ,MAX(MAX(Id)) OVER (
        PARTITION BY pp.Sedol
        ,MAX(pp.ValueDate)
        ) PriceId
FROM @Prices pp
GROUP BY pp.Sedol

-- Simple SQL mentioned by Lamak
SELECT Sedol, MAX(Id) PriceId FROM @Prices GROUP BY Sedol
```

Resultset :

[image]